# Bootstrap CSS3 added to support softsimon angular-2-multiselect-drop down is modifying the CSS porperties of other components in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I linked bootstrap CSS3 in my index.html file of angular 2 project . These styles sheets are changing the CSS properties of the other components.How do i solve it ? I tried even making a copy of the Bootstrap CSS3.css and Linking it using StylUrls . Nothing happens.

How do i over ride them ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override the styles, then you would have to attach your custom style sheet after the link to bootstrap style sheet in your index.html.
As a rule of thumb the last css overrides styles of the previous styles if any. If this doesnt work, then in your style sheet add '!important'tag after declaring your styles like so :

```
.class{ 
    color : #d3d3d3!important;//'!important' overrides the precedent style if any
 }
```